# How many users have a specific role

Tags: discord.py

i am creating a bot for a specific server and i would like to insert in a command how many users have a specific role.

I don't know how

Here is the part I set, I miss the variables:

```
embed.add_field(
        name=f'I membri totali del {name_server} sono suddivisi in:',
        value=f'{triumvirato}: **{count_triumvirato}**\n{co_triumvirato}: **{count_co_triumvirato}**\n{presidente}: **{count_presidente}**\n{senatore}: **{count_senatore}**\n{moderatore}: **{count_moderatore}**\n{membro}: **{count_membro}**\n{accademico}: **{count_accademico}**\n{onorario}: **{count_onorario}**\n{gamer}: **{count_gamer}**\n{clandestino}: **{count_clandestino}**\n\nI membri ufficiali sono **{official_member_count}** e se contassimo pure gli accademici il totale salirebbe a **{official_e_accademici_member_count}**\nIl resto è composto da **{non_official_member_count}**',
        inline=False
    )
```

Here all the variables that I should set but that I have no idea:

```
#specific member info
    triumvirato = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_triumvirato = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    co_triumvirato = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_co_triumvirato = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    presidente = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_presidente = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    senatore = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_senatore = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    moderatore = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_moderatore = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    membro = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_membro = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    accademico = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_accademico = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    onorario = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_onorario = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    gamer = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_gamer = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    clandestino = #specific role to mention in the embed
    count_clandestino = #here must give the total number of users who have a specific role
    official_member_count = # sum in the top 6 (from triumvirato to membro)
    official_e_accademici_member_count = # sum between official_member_count and accademico
    non_official_member_count = # sum between onorario, gamers and clandestino
```

I hope someone helps me would please me so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from discord.utils import get
#inside command
guild = ctx.guild
role = get(guild.roles, name='Name')
user_with_role = [m for m in guild.members if role in m.roles]
```

This should return a list of members having a role named `Name`, doing `len` of the list returns the number of users.
`no = len(user_with_role)`

Comment: thank you very much but how do I do for the sums between these variables?

Comment: Well ideally all you'd need is to do `len(user_with_role)` and you will get the number of users having a particular role.

Comment: I had asked a separate question but I found the solution myself and I wrote it.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923248?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    i = 0
    guild = ctx.guild
    for roles in guild.roles:
        if roles.name == "YOUR ROLE NAME":
            for member in guild.members:
                for member_role in member.roles:
                    if member_role.name == roles.name:
                       i += 1
```

This is another method to do this. "i" will return you the number of users that have this role.

Comment: I prefer the first method is much faster but this is also excellent.